# Problems running demo application

Tags: java, intuit-partner-platform

As far as I can determine I have followed the steps as detailed at https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0200_DevKits_for_Intuit_Partner_Platform/Sample_Apps/Java_Sample_App_for_AggCat_Services/0010_Creating_the_App for running the java demo application.

After enabling the logs, I see following entries in the log output

```
DEBUG: com.intuit.aggcat.logger - Response code=401
DEBUG: com.intuit.aggcat.logger - OAuth access tokens = null
DEBUG: com.intuit.aggcat.logger -  Could not get oAuth tokens: null
```

So I think server thinks I don't have permissions, however intuit developer website shows I have test access permissions for Customer Account Data API. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.

By the way I think documentation at above link is cut off. Very Last statement says "run as" but does not say run as what

Comment: Did you insert the OAuth tokens into the configuration?

Comment: @William, If you are referring to steps 5.f and 5.g in above linked document, then yes. Otherwise, can you please let me know what needs to be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you try using the API explorer (developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer) with the same set of keys to verify that the keys and cert used are correct. If you are able to retrieve the tokens through the API Explorer, then you should be able to do the same through the Java sample app.

Answer (score 0):

You should login to the sample app with the username "user"